# Unity GVR Cardboard Camera incorrect work on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I have prepared unity environment to work with Google VR cardboard. Sample project performs fine and all is good.
In my project I have Main Camera object, which moves across the scene. I've added "Strereo Controller" (Script) component to the camera and it works fine in Unity editor. But when I start project on Android device camera stand still on one place and doesn't move. What can it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't move the VR Camera, it's the SDK that determine the *mainCamera* position.

In order to move your camera you can just make a new `GameObject` as a parent of your `mainCamera` then move the parent `GameObject`

Comment: @widesteppe No problem! if i can help :)