# Unity GvrMain properties work differently on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, daydream

I spent about 45min starting my first hello unity daydream app, and found that it runs differently on my Android device than on my PC.  I'm using Unity 5.6.1f1 Personal(64bit), Windows 10 64bit, Pixel XL 7.1, and a download of the Google-VR-SDK from about May 15, 2017 (I don't know how to check the version of that).

My app just has a "Map" object which uses a script to generate the environment geometry with a capsule collider, and a GvrMain object (found in Unity under GoogleVR->Legacy->Prefabs->GvrMain) positioned above the center of the map, with a capsule collider and rigidbody.

On the PC, the GvrMain starts just above the map and drops down until it collides with the map and stops.  On Android, the GvrMain just floats above the map, and does not drop down.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610722/unity-gvr-cardboard-camera-incorrect-work-on-android), I saw a comment that only the Google VR SDK can control the GvrMain position.  So I created an empty "Player" object, moved the GvrMain under that object, and also moved the capsule collider, rigid body, and start position from GvrMain to the Player parent object.

But the results were the same: the player or camera falls to the map on PC, but hovers above the map on Android.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you press play in the editor, the version number of GVR will be printed in the Unity console.

You should download the latest plugin, as some things have changed.  There is no longer a GvrMain.  In Unity, the main camera is set to render stereo, and the rotation of that camera is controlled by the engine.  Everything else is up to you.

Any prefabs labelled 'legacy' are just that - they are legacy code released only for developers who may need to maintain existing applications.